# How to add logic to custom spree step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkout, spree

I have read alot of the tutorials and the spree guides but my major question is how to add step logic (saving and such), I have a step before the payment step it basically chooses if the user wants pickup (which will make the price cheaper) or a delivery.
Now the thing is i got the views working properly and the step movements, but I cannot get anything to save.

Now in the edge guides I get confused with the checkout process as one thing it says to use the state machine but then talks about the checkout flow option which really messes me up

So my question is what is the proper way to add a step to the checkout process and do you use both the checkout_flow DSL and the state_machine or one or the other.

My spree is version 1.3.2
Currently no added extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out in my case.
Since I only want to add something to the order (e.g. a column) I just add

```
attr_accessible :column_name
```

and inside the form i just make sure that the column_name is a parameter that is passed, looks like spree takes care of the rest. I just dont really know how to add that extra validation logic but that is something I will work on, and Update for others when I do figure it out.